# R way to program multiple regression in particular way?

Tags: r, statistics, r-markdown, linear-regression

I'm doing research into language use for two brand segments (high-end and low-end). Each brand segment is divided into 3 brands (6 total). To look at the difference between them, I look at several factors which the brands use. One might do so more than the other. I want to find out which language factor can be predicted to be used more in one segment or the other.

Any ideas on how to get started visualizing this data in R(see image)? What model could I use etc.
[image: On the far left are the brands, and after the 'tweet' section come all the factors]

Answer (score 0):

Simms a problem for tidytextmining.
You find the book, parts of it online: https://www.tidytextmining.com
Learned much from the book.